# SQL SELECT With Stored Procedure and Parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, sql-server-2008, web

I've been writing a lot of web services with SQL inserts based on a stored procedure, and I haven't really worked with any SELECTS.

The one `SELECT` I have in mind is very simple.

```
SELECT COUNT(AD_SID) As ReturnCount FROM AD_Authorization
WHERE AD_SID = @userSID
```

However, I can't figure out based on my current `INSERT` code how to make that into a `SELECT` and return the value of `ReturnCount`... Can you help? Here is my `INSERT` code:

```
string ConnString = "Data Source=Removed";
string SqlString = "spInsertProgress";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
   using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
   {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("attachment_guid", smGuid.ToString());
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("attachment_percentcomplete", fileProgress);
      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is where you are going wrong:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You *are* executing a query.

You need to [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8acxyzc3.aspx) or [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead. `ExecuteReader` is used for a result set (several rows/columns), `ExecuteScalar` when the query returns a single result (it returns `object`, so the result needs to be cast to the correct type).

```
var result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

The `results` variable will now hold a [`OledbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.aspx) or a value with the results of the `SELECT`. You can iterate over the results (for a reader), or the scalar value (for a scalar).

Comment: Or if a single row, single column is returned (like a `COUNT` here): `.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: @marc_s - Quite right... realized just after writing my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are only after a single value, you can use cmd.ExecuteScalar();

A complete example is as follows:

```
    string ConnString = "Data Source=Removed"; 
    string userSid = "SomeSid";
    string SqlString = "SELECT COUNT(AD_SID) As ReturnCount FROM AD_Authorization WHERE AD_SID = @userSID;"; 
    int returnCount = 0;
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString)) 
    { 
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)) 
        { 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userSID", userSid); 
            conn.Open(); 
            returnCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
        } 
    }
```

If you wanted to return MULTIPLE rows, you can use the ExecuteReader() method. This returns an IDataReader via which you can enumerate the result set row by row.

Comment: Getting Must declare the scalar variable "@userSID" when doing this.. any idea?

Comment: Actually i got this fixed by adding the declare in the SQL string. Problem is it always returns 0, but when i run it in SSMS it returns 3. Code to follow

Comment: Also, what's the underlying type of the column "AD_SID"? Is it a GUID?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(AD_SID) As ReturnCount FROM AD_Authorization WHERE AD_SID = @userSID ";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString)) {
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userSID", userSID.ToString());
        conn.Open();
        int returnCount = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting Must declare the scalar variable "@userSID" when doing this.. any idea?

Comment: The `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userSID", userSID.ToString());` is the declaration part. Did you add it in your code? What type is the userSID column?

Comment: Its not a SID, i would have used a uniqueidentifier column then.  Its a windows security identitifer, which is also encrypted with TripleAES

Comment: The code of my answer should work. If not, I suggest you to ask another question precising the error you get. It's hard for me through comments to understand what doesn't work now :)

Answer (score 0):

cmd.executescalar will return a single value, such as your count.

You would use cmd.executereader when you are returning a list of records