# SELECT statement with COUNT Always Returns 0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Don't know why I can't reply to people on here with only a small amount of comment text, but my revised code exceeds that so I'm posting new.

This web service always returns 0. If I run it in SSMS it returns 3... not sure why, any ideas?

```
string ConnString = "Removed";
String query = "DECLARE @userSID varchar(255) SELECT COUNT(AD_SID) As ReturnCount FROM AD_Authorization WHERE AD_SID = @userSID ";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
   using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
   {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("userSID", SpartaCrypto.SpartaEncryptAES(userSID.ToString(), "s3cret!"));
      conn.Open();
      int returnCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
      conn.Close();

      if (returnCount > 1) 
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 0;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: a) Shouldn't the test be `returnCount >= 1`? (probably a typo in the post). b) remove the 'declare ..' and keep only the 'select' part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL SELECT With Stored Procedure and Parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377783/sql-select-with-stored-procedure-and-parameters)

Comment: Don't re-post. You can Edit your questions (until they are correct).

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Not a dupe. Different issue now.

Comment: What **database** are you going against?? If SQL Server: why are you using the old OleDb stuff and not the newer `SqlConnection/SqlCommand` classes? Also: have you debugged through? What is the value of `returnCount` after the call to `.ExecuteScalar()` ??

Comment: Marc, do you have a better example? This was written a while ago so whatever the best way is would be great.  Im using SQL server 2008. with Oded's answer of using "SELECT COUNT(AD_SID) As ReturnCount FROM AD_Authorization WHERE AD_SID = ?" fixed the issue and returnCount now shows the correct value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not a good OLEDB parameterized query.

Try this instead:

```
"SELECT COUNT(AD_SID) As ReturnCount FROM AD_Authorization WHERE AD_SID = @userSID";
```

Also, the parameter name should match:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userSID", SpartaCrypto.SpartaEncryptAES(userSID.ToString(), "s3cret!"));
```

Comment: Glad to see you got your issue solved. If you are using SQL Server, think about marc_S's comment above. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, it makes me wait 10m after it was posted... silly.. anyways its marked now, thanks again! :)